How to load angular app with flutter webview
I am working on a Flutter app that loads an existing Angular web app in a WebView. But i'm facing an issue at the level of file upload, which is a feature of the angular app. When the user click on the file upload input, nothing happens. I've added the permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in the android manifest, subsquently, that did not solve the matter. Can Someone please help me find a solution to this situation please?
